# Cython GIL SIGSEGV

Tags: cython, ld-preload

I'm getting a segmentation violation when trying to intercept calls via LD_PRELOAD from Cython. I don't understand why though?

```
"""An experiment in shimming from Cython / Python."""

cdef extern from "dlfcn.h":
    void* dlsym(void*, char*)
    void* RTLD_NEXT

cdef extern int execvp(const char *file, char *const argv[]) with gil:
    print "Intercepted lookup of %r" % file
    libc_execvp = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "execvp")
    if libc_execvp:
        with nogil:
            return (<int(*)(const char*, char * const *) nogil>libc_execvp)(file, argv)
    return -1
```

The project with an example test case is available at https://github.com/CraigJPerry/pyshim/blob/master/pyshim/pyshim.pyx

I believe the python runtime may not be correctly initialised and this is the root of my issue?

```
[craig@d1 pyshim](master)$ gdb env
..
Reading symbols from /usr/bin/env...Reading symbols from /usr/bin/env...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
(gdb) set environment LD_PRELOAD=pyshim/pyshim.so
(gdb) set args echo
(gdb) run
Starting program: /usr/bin/env echo
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib64/libthread_db.so.1".

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x000000396ee0ddb0 in sem_wait () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
(gdb) bt
#0  0x000000396ee0ddb0 in sem_wait () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x0000003bbcf0c7b5 in PyThread_acquire_lock ()
   from /lib64/libpython2.7.so.1.0
#2  0x0000003bbcefad80 in ?? () from /lib64/libpython2.7.so.1.0
#3  0x0000003bbcefb62c in PyGILState_Ensure () from /lib64/libpython2.7.so.1.0
#4  0x00007ffff7df9519 in execvp (__pyx_v_file=0x7fffffffe85b "echo", 
    __pyx_v_argv=0x7fffffffe4d0) at pyshim/pyshim.c:681
#5  0x0000000000401a82 in main ()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cython assumes you have a functional Python interpreter running (i.e. that you are writing an *extension module*). In this case, you are *embedding* Python, rather than *extending* it. So you need to do some extra work to initialize everything.

Luckily, this is not really a challenging problem:

```
"""An experiment in shimming from Cython / Python."""

cdef extern from "dlfcn.h":
    void* dlsym(void*, char*)
    void* RTLD_NEXT

cdef extern from "Python.h":
    void Py_Initialize() nogil

cdef extern void initpyshim()

cdef extern int execvp(const char *file, char *const argv[]) nogil: # note nogil here
    Py_Initialize() # initialize Python
    with gil:
        initpyshim() # initialize containing module
        print "Intercepted lookup of %r" % file
        libc_execvp = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "execvp")
        if libc_execvp:
            with nogil:
                return (<int(*)(const char*, char * const *) nogil>libc_execvp)(file, argv)
        return -1
```

If your function may be called multiple times, you may want to avoid re-initializing your module (you can do this by checking `Py_IsInitialized()`). You may also need to call `Py_Finalize()` before leaving your method.

If you are targeting Python 3, the init method is called `PyInit_<modname>` and returns a `PyObject *` reference that you need to hold on to until the end of the method (at the very least).